# Importing org.apache.commons Java

Tags: java, apache, class, jar

I've been trying to import the apache commons inside my jar, but can't see to do it. This code below is the code I'm using:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;


public class Java extends Applet
{
  public void init()
  {
    String str1 = "testing.html"
    String str2 = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
     try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.facebook.com");
            File destination = new File(str2 + str1);
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

I compiled it with the command prompt:

```
set /p c=Please choose a signature name: 
keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias %c%
keytool.exe -export -alias %c% -file Certificate.crt
javac.exe Java.java -cp commons.jar
jar.exe cvf Java.jar *.class commons.jar
jarsigner.exe Java.jar %c%
```

Finally we got my HTML code to run it:

```
<applet width='100px' height='200px' code='Java.class' archive="Java.jar, commons.jar">
</applet>
```

Now when I run it, it wont download the file and place it in the temp folder. Why is that?

Comment: Are you trying to place a jar file in another jar file? Are you distributing the commons jar with your application (not jarred inside of it)?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to place the `commons.jar` inside your other JAR file; that won't work. You need to place it on the webserver in the same directory as your other JAR file. The browser can't download a file that doesn't exist on the server, and no code on the server is going to unpack that JAR.

Comment: looks familiar :) (see comment above).

Comment: How would I got about doing so?